# How to resize a search text box of a website (eg. LinkedIn) in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

I want to resize the search text box so that I can easily and see and edit long strings directly in it.
Is there any way to do that by modifying some CSS values(or HTML)?

Below is the text box of LinkedIn job search that I wanna make wider and taller:

[image: Below is the text box of LinkedIn job search that I wanna make wider and taller]

[image: CSS elements, can't find any width or height attributes in that]

Comment: Type it in notepad, copy, paste into search bar.

Comment: I have been doing that, but it is becoming tedious at scale, so that doesn't solve it

Comment: You have now lost the image that was originally in your question. It would also help if you could create your own example (probably just a simple input element in a snippet) which we could use as a basis for describing how to do this.

Comment: Edit: added original image and a pic of the CSS elements where i cant find any height or width attribute

Answer (score 1):

Use width and height property in css.

Comment: I have added original image and a pic of the CSS elements where i cant find any height or width attribute

Comment: If using chrome or firefox, right-click and select "inspect" after that select element you want to see CSS property and open the "computed" tab and can check all property you can find heigh and width property there. Double click on that and it will take you to style where you can edit it and can check to effect their only

Answer (score 0):

You could use tampermonkey/greasemonkey or "page manipulator" plugin if you're talking about manipulating existing websites

Comment: I have added original image and a pic of the CSS elements where i cant find any height or width attribute

Comment: Styling is in its own section of the inspector. In Google Chrome at least. Anyway, that might not help you anyway, as changes there are not persistent

Answer (score 0):

right click on text box and then click inspect.
a window like bar will open in that see right side you will see css
in that you can increse or decrease height or width

Comment: I have added original image and a pic of the CSS elements where i cant find any height or width attribute

Answer (score 0):

If using chrome or firefox, right-click and select "inspect" after that select element you want to see CSS property and open the "computed" tab and can check all property you can find heigh and width property there. Double click on that and it will take you to style where you can edit it and can check to effect their only.

[image]